# PUT Form resulting in 404 Not Found (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model, User a UserController and a login form with PUT specified as the method. My route is also defined and matches the form route. When submitting the form I get a error 404 Not Found.

I have tried naming the route to no avail.

User Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = "panel_users";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    public $incrementing = true;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];
}
```

UserController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $user = new User;
        return view('login', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function attemptLogin(Request $request, User $user) {
        error_log($user);
        session(['username' => $user->username]);
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Form

```
{{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['login.attemptlogin', $user], 'method' => 'PUT']) }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username: ') }}
                        {{ Form::text('username', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password: ') }}
                        {{ Form::text('password', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Login</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Route defined

```
Route::put('/login/attemptlogins/{user}', 'UserController@attemptLogin')->name('login.attemptlogin');
```

Should set the add the username to the session variable and output the model to the console. Neither of which happen.

Comment: can you show the exact error?

Comment: Are you caching your routes? You might want to try `php artisan route:clear` or `php artisan cache:clear` to clear your cache.

Comment: There is no error apart from the 404 Not Found page being displayed. I cleared the cache and that didn't fix it. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Try with this,

```
{{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['login.attemptlogin', $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) }}
```

In controller

```
public function attemptLogin(Request $request, $id) {
    // ...
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this didn't fix it.

Comment: try to dd $id in controller. See it getting id or not

Comment: I added a line to output the ID to the console, nothing is being outputted when I submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

you must change

```
{{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['login.attemptlogin', $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix it unfortunately.